# Replace code to fertch all Orders from Database

Tags: order-details

I am new in Magento. I am trying to fetch **Order** related values from Database.I used `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderNumber);` this code previously. I retrieved all others values using that code. Here I used a specific **OrderNumber**. But now I would like to retrieve all values of Orders from Database. I would like to just replace this code `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderNumber);` so that I can use rest of the code.

Which code can I use here ?? Can anyone help me in this regard ??

Answer (score 0):

To get all the orders, try below code :

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
foreach ($orders as $order) {
     echo "<pre>";print_r($order->getData()); // print order details
}
```